# Android - How do I keep a sticky snackbar when a new snackbar appears?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-snackbar, snackbar

I have a sticky `Snackbar` (`Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE`). 
In some cases, there is another temporary `Snackbar` (either `long` or `short`) that should appear as well. 
The new temporary `Snackbar` automatically dismisses the sticky one. I would like to keep the sticky one behind the temporary one, so that when the temporary `Snackbar` disappears, the sticky one is still shown.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: You could add a callback to the temporary ones so that they show the indefinite again when they dismiss.

Comment: If you check out `Snackbar` source code, you will find it uses an internal singleton object `SnackbarManager` that provides only basic behavior of prolonging current `Snackbar` or replacing it with new one. You'd need to create 
a custom layout mimicking `Snackbar` for permanent one, or use dismiss callbacks of temporary one.